# Finding illegitimate boy after birth in 1903?

Tags: census-records, scotland

Edward James Logan Reid was born in May 1903 to Margaret Reid. I can find no record of him until 1923 in Canada as Edward James Fraser. Margaret had married James Fraser in Ontario in 1915.

Where was he?

Who was his father?

He was well educated. He never married and his history only became provided after my mother, his sister died. A real mystery.

And where did the name Logan come from?

He was born in Edinburgh and died in Brampton, Ontario.

Comment: Hello Jo-Anne, and welcome to G&FH.SE! Have you found Edward's birth record? It appears to be on the [Scotland's People](https://www.scotlandspeople.gov.uk/) database - search for his full name around 1903 and one record is found. You do need an account and to purchase credits to view it, though. It's probably the best bet for a father's name, but there's no guarantee there will be one.

Comment: Thanks. I did find his birth certificate but no father listed.

Answer (score 1):

If his mother married in 1915 in Ontario and he was there in 1923, then the first place I would look is the 1921 census of Canada.

Then, for his entry into Canada (probably with his mother).

Then, depending on when that was, the 1911 census of Canada or the 1911 census of Scotland.

I presume you have a copy of his birth certificate.

For each of these documents, addresses, name variations, and who they live or travel with may provide a hint towards his biological father.

"Logan" is highly likely to be his father's surname so you might also look to see if there are many persons by that name in the area where he was born or where his mother lived.

Comment: He did not come to Canada with his mother so wouldn`t be on the 21 census. No copy just Scotlands People record. Thanks. hope to go to Scotland to find out.